# How can I find the integer solutions of $17x+13y=282$?

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

I am trying to find a reliable fast way to find the integer solutions for equations such as $17x+13y=282$. I need to know as fast as possible if such equation has only 1 pair of integers $x,y$ that meet the equation, or more than one.

What would be the best method to approach such a problem? Thank you.

Ps. Assume I have no calculator. Just pen and paper.

Comment: Do the examples from [*Rosen*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yJIMx9nXB6kC&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282&dq=17x%2B13y%3D282&source=bl&ots=1ShgXcljPV&sig=aRVlTuXUWnoeAImtnEvLPXhosUs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-sKzf0p3eAhVI0oMKHUO2BwoQ6AEwBHoECE0QAQ#v=onepage&q=17x%2B13y%3D282&f=false) help?

Comment: I am blown away by the speed and depth of the help here. Thank you so much everyone. I understand the main concept now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [linear Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations).  The techniques for solving are well-known.  If there is one solution, then there are infinitely many, so there is no case in which there is just one solution.

Since the $\gcd(17,13) =1,$ first find a solution to $17x+13y = 1$.  Then multiply the solution by $282$.  Then whatever the solution is, you can add any multiple of $13$ to $x$ and subtract the same multiple of $17$ from $y$ and get another solution.

Comment: Also look up the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find the solution to $ 17x + 13y = 1$ if you have not seen this before, @TBM

Answer (score 0):

$4\cdot 13 = 52\\
3\cdot 17 = 51\\
4\cdot 13 - 3\cdot 17 = 1$

$x = -282(3), y = 282(4)$ is a solution.

$x = -846 + 13k, y = 1128 - 17k$

If you want to add the additional criteria that $x,y \in \mathbb N$

then $\frac {846}{13} = 65 \frac 1{13}$ and $\frac {1128}{17} = 66 \frac {6}{17}$

Then there is only one $k = 66$ that satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ 4(13) -3(17)=1$$

Therefore $$ 4(282)(13)-3(282)(17)=282 $$

Thus $x= -3(282)=-846 $ and  $y= 4(282)=1128$